# WP8 app crashes with SEHException exception

Tags: windows-phone-8

Recently, my app often raise a crash when it starts, the below is its call stack:

{System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)}

Do you know why, and where is the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Have you investigated this any more?